# Is it true that most copy machines have hard drives in them, that store an image of every copy they've ever made?

Tags: hard-drive

I read [this over at CBS News](http://www.cbsnews.com/stories/2010/04/19/eveningnews/main6412439.shtml).

Comment: I wonder if FedEx/Kinkos erases their hard drives when they sell them.

Comment: @Stefan Highly doubtful. There's no economic incentive for them to do so (unless you consider lawsuits that could occur after data is misused).

Comment: And I always assumed that photocopiers used encryption, or that the stored documents had a limited life. I guess it's been a while since I maintained photocopiers and fax machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all photocopiers have storage of some sort, and in IT security, this is a major issue. All IT security shops will tell you to trash/destroy the hard disk before getting rid of a photocopier, or even sending it for maintenance. Some companies such as Canon are telling everyone that their photocopiers, which use hard disks have built-in file overwriting systems that are military-grade.

This is true regardless of whether a photocopier has or has no network port. Today's photocopiers are mainly a scanner coupled with some graphic engine for graphics effects or transformation and a laser printer. If you are printing sensitive content, be careful where you photocopy it.

JF

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the article:

> Nearly *every digital copier built since 2002* contains a hard drive - like the one on your personal computer - storing an image of every document copied, scanned, or emailed by the machine.

I would think the Golden Rule here is: **if the machine at hand has an ethernet port**, use another one to Xerox you passport or any private part of your body.